# Fast way to import and crop a jpeg in python lib

Tags: python, image-processing, jpeg

I have a python app that imports 200k+ images, crops them, and presents the cropped image to pyzbar to interpret a barcode. Cropping helps because there are multiple barcodes on the image and, presumably pyzbar is a little faster when given smaller images.

Currently I am using Pillow to import and crop the image.

On the average importing and cropping an image takes 262 msecs and pyzbar take 8 msecs.

A typical run is about 21 hours.

I wonder if a library other than Pillow might offer substantial improvements in loading/cropping. Ideally the library should be available for MacOS but I could also run the whole thing in a virtual Ubuntu machine.

I am working on a version that can run in parallel processes which will be a big improvement but if I could get 25% or more speed increase from a different library I would also add that.

Comment: Python is not the go-to language for high-performance computing.

Comment: Perhaps if you posted some code we could comment on the efficiency, and without knowing the size of images, we cannot really say if 262 ms is slow or fast, although a gut reaction is slow. Also have you tried OpenCV or even ImageMagick's batch facilities?

Comment: "I wonder if a library other than Pillow might offer substantial improvements in loading/cropping." You could test that with different libraries.

Comment: @KenY-N suggested i post some code. Here it is:

      imgc = Image.open(infile).crop((0, 150, 270, 1050))

The input files are all jpgs of 2544x4200 px and range from 500KB to 1.5MB dpending on how much white space is on the page. The average time for this step is 250 msec.

Comment: @Trilarion: Clearly I can. I was  hoping someone had and would share their experience.

Comment: You could also time the load and crop operations separately. My guess is that cropping is much faster than loading which would reduce the whole problem to the fastest way of loading images. For speeding up the experiment then also the performance of the hardware IO would be interesting.

Comment: @Trilarion at least 90% of the time is spend loading and decompressing the jpeg, and then most of the data is throwing away in the crop. I phrased it the way I did on the hope that maybe someone knew of an algorithm that saved decompression time by using the crop information in advance. I recognize that this is far from trivial but it's really the only way I see to make a significant improvement.

Comment: pyvips will only decompress the part of the JPEG you end up using. Mark has some nice example code below.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I saw it and it looks good, but I haven't had time to try it yet. It is on my todo list and I will be delighted to check it as solving the problem after that.

Answer (score 8):

As you didn't provide a sample image, I made a dummy file with dimensions 2544x4200 at 1.1MB in size and it is provided at the end of the answer. I made 1,000 copies of that image and processed all 1,000 images for each benchmark.

As you only gave your code in the comments area, I took it, formatted it and made the best I could of it. I also put it in a loop so it can process many files for just one invocation of the Python interpreter - this becomes important when you have 20,000 files.

That looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PIL import Image

# Process all input files so we only incur Python startup overhead once
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
   print(f'Processing: {filename}')
   imgc = Image.open(filename).crop((0, 150, 270, 1050))
```

My suspicion is that I can make that faster using:

- GNU Parallel, and/or
- pyvips

Here is a `pyvips` version of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import pyvips
import numpy as np

# Process all input files so we only incur Python startup overhead once
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
   print(f'Processing: {filename}')

   img = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(filename, access='sequential')
   roi = img.crop(0, 150, 270, 900)
   mem_img = roi.write_to_memory()

   # Make a numpy array from that buffer object
   nparr = np.ndarray(buffer=mem_img, dtype=np.uint8,
                   shape=[roi.height, roi.width, roi.bands])
```

Here are the results:

## Sequential original code

```
./orig.py bc*jpg
224 seconds, i.e. 224 ms per image, same as you
```

## Parallel original code

```
parallel ./orig.py ::: bc*jpg
55 seconds
```

## Parallel original code but passing as many filenames as possible

```
parallel -X ./orig.py ::: bc*jpg
42 seconds
```

## Sequential pyvips

```
./vipsversion bc*
30 seconds, i.e. 7x as fast as PIL which was 224 seconds
```

## Parallel pyvips

```
parallel ./vipsversion ::: bc*
32 seconds
```

## Parallel pyvips but passing as many filenames as possible

```
parallel -X ./vipsversion ::: bc*
5.2 seconds, i.e. this is the way to go :-)
```

[image]

---

Note that you can install **GNU Parallel** on macOS with **homebrew**:

```
brew install parallel
```

Comment: Nice! You can make the pyvips one a bit quicker with `new_from_file(filename, access='sequential')`. It'll only bother decoding the cropped area.

Comment: @jcupitt Excellent, thank you! I'll try it out later on, or tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Oh, the way that works: `sequential` mode will stream the image from the source file to the destination memory area. Because the jpg is being decompressed on demand, once demand stops, the decompression will be abandoned. So in this case it'll only decompress as far as line 1200 and ignore the other 3000 lines.

Comment: @jcupitt Mmmm, that improved sequential and `parallel -X` significantly but made the middle one worse... not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Oh, OK, yes, with only one image cropped per invocation, start/stop time dominates. I see 1000 crops in 10s with sequential pyvips, 2.6s with parallel pyvips.

Comment: @jcupitt I think I'll leave it in. I want to be honest, and actually it illustrates what I said at the start about overhead of starting a whole new Python interpreter per image. Thank you for your insights again.

Comment: Thank you for de-clumsifying my beginner’s Python too.

Comment: Oh heh no problem. You could swap the format lines for format strings too, if you like: `f'Processing: {filename}'` is slightly neater.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look on [PyTurboJPEG](https://github.com/lilohuang/PyTurboJPEG) which is a Python wrapper of [libjpeg-turbo](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo) with insanely fast rescaling (1/2, 1/4, 1/8) while decoding large JPEG image, the returning numpy.ndarray is handy for image cropping. Moreover, JPEG image encoding speed is also remarkable.

```
from turbojpeg import TurboJPEG

# specifying library path explicitly
# jpeg = TurboJPEG(r'D:\turbojpeg.dll')
# jpeg = TurboJPEG('/usr/lib64/libturbojpeg.so')
# jpeg = TurboJPEG('/usr/local/lib/libturbojpeg.dylib')

# using default library installation
jpeg = TurboJPEG()

# direct rescaling 1/2 while decoding input.jpg to BGR array
in_file = open('input.jpg', 'rb')
bgr_array_half = jpeg.decode(in_file.read(), scaling_factor=(1, 2))
in_file.close()

# encoding BGR array to output.jpg with default settings.
out_file = open('output.jpg', 'wb')
out_file.write(jpeg.encode(bgr_array))
out_file.close()
```

libjpeg-turbo prebuilt binaries for macOS and Linux are also available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/files/2.0.2/).